# Nested HTML ul Element to JSON

Tags: html, jquery, json, angular

I want to make a form builder application using drag and drop. I have a main `<li>` tag. There are other `<li>` and `<ul>` tags in the nested structure under this tag.

As a requirement of my application I need to get this structure as JSON. I think I should use a recursive function but I failed. I am using Angular and jQuery. Can you help me?

```html
<li id="mainList" style="list-style: none;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul class="sortable ui-sortable">
        <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Text Field" data-type="1" data-element-id="n8b78496-04bd">
          <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
            <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Text Field</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Text Field" disabled="">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Number" data-type="3" data-element-id="nbdbeecb-ff2d">
          <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
            <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Number</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Number" disabled="">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="n9cdfd2a-95ea" data-is-component="false" data-type-text="Column 2" data-type="60" data-element-id="n9cdfd2a-95ea">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <ul class="sortable ui-sortable">
                <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Choice" data-type="5" data-element-id="n4488d94-bf63">
                  <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
                    <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Choice</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Choice" disabled="">
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <ul class="sortable ui-sortable">
                <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Select Box" data-type="6" data-element-id="n1179190-213f">
                  <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
                    <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Select Box</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Select Box" disabled="">
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Date / Time" data-type="7" data-element-id="n2cd4518-633e">
                  <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
                    <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Date / Time</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Date / Time" disabled="">
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Color" data-type="11" data-element-id="n6103ae8-67e4">
          <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
            <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Color</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Color" disabled="">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

The JSON output I'm trying to create:

```js
{
  "id": "mainList",
  "childs": [{
      "id": "n8b78496-04bd",
      "childs": null
    },
    {
      "id": "nbdbeecb-ff2d",
      "childs": null
    },
    {
      "id": "n9cdfd2a-95ea",
      "childs": [
        [{
          "id": "n4488d94-bf63",
          "childs": null
        }],
        [{
          "id": "n1179190-213f",
          "childs": null
        }, {
          "id": "n2cd4518-633e",
          "childs": null
        }]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "n6103ae8-67e4",
      "childs": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function that collects the `li` elements it finds at the next level, creates objects for them and then uses recursion to do the same for each child:

```js
const collectChildren = (elem) => elem.tagName == "UL" 
        ? [...elem.children]
        : Array.from(elem.children, collectChildren).flat();

function collectListItems(li) {
    const children = collectChildren(li);
    return {
        id: li.dataset.elementId ?? li.id,
        children: children.length ? Array.from(children, collectListItems) : null
    };
}

const result = collectListItems(document.getElementById("mainList"));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="mainList" style="list-style: none;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <ul class="sortable ui-sortable">
            <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Text Field" data-type="1" data-element-id="n8b78496-04bd">
              <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
                <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Text Field</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Text Field" disabled="">
              </div>
            </li>
            <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Number" data-type="3" data-element-id="nbdbeecb-ff2d">
              <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
                <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Number</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Number" disabled="">
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id="n9cdfd2a-95ea" data-is-component="false" data-type-text="Column 2" data-type="60" data-element-id="n9cdfd2a-95ea">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <ul class="sortable ui-sortable">
                    <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Choice" data-type="5" data-element-id="n4488d94-bf63">
                      <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
                        <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Choice</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Choice" disabled="">
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <ul class="sortable ui-sortable">
                    <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Select Box" data-type="6" data-element-id="n1179190-213f">
                      <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
                        <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Select Box</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Select Box" disabled="">
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Date / Time" data-type="7" data-element-id="n2cd4518-633e">
                      <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
                        <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Date / Time</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Date / Time" disabled="">
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li data-is-component="true" data-type-text="Color" data-type="11" data-element-id="n6103ae8-67e4">
              <div class="form-group builder-component mt-1">
                <label style="font-size:smaller" for="exampleFormControlInput1">Color</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Color" disabled="">
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```